# How will gravity behave in a fourth spatial dimension?

Tags: gravity, spacetime-dimensions

If we were somehow able to see or experience the fourth spatial dimension, how would gravity act on us in there? Does the direction of the pull change? Will it have any effect on light or anything else?

Comment: *"If we were somehow able to see or experience the fourth spatial dimension"*...that doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I can give a good answer, but the 4th dimension gets pretty weird and a few things would happen.

First, the direction of pull wouldn't change, it would be towards the massive object.   There would be more directions to travel (up/down, back/forward, left/right and 4th-one way/4th-the other), but the pull would still be directly towards the object and any orbit would still be elliptical around the object.

The strength of gravitational pull would weaken by the cube of the distance, not the square of the distance, so gravitation would weaken over distance quite a bit faster.

There's a cool video that touches on what solar systems and galaxies would look like in 4D (the 4D part starts about 2 minutes in).   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM

Also, in 4d, density could grow much faster cause there's more space, matter could pack more tightly (and I don't want to guess how the electron shells would be affected).   But a cubic KM of water is 1 billion cubic meters, a bit over 1 billion tons.    a quadric (not sure that's the right word), or a KM to the 4th, in 4 dimensions would be a trillion meters to the 4th, a thousand times as many.   In theory, gravity would be much stronger close to a large object, but it would grow weaker faster. - this is, of-course, a pretty rough answer, as the 4th dimension doesn't exist in that sense, so it's only theoretical.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but your statement about elliptical orbits in higher dimensions is not correct. According to Bertram's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem only the harmonic oscillator and the 1/r potential (i.e. the Kepler problem in three dimensions) have closed orbits, so at the very least 4d planets would show strong perihelion shift and possible orbital instability. One can possibly extend this result to the non-existence of regular quantum mechanical solutions, i.e. the non-existence of 4d matter as we know it.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand I'm commenting on a 7 year-old answer, but the general math convention is to just add the number of topological dimensions to any extension of an object to the higher dimension; “quadric” is a sensible but obscure term. In 4D, there are 4-balls and 4-cubes, so 4-cubic is understandable to everyone. Surfaces are confusing at first, tho, 'cus they're "one less" dimensional: "normal" sphere embedded into $E^3$ is a 2-sphere, as is 2-torus (we normally speak of the surface of the torus). 1-sphere is a circle, and 0-sphere is a set of 2 points on the real line, $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: @kkm  I appreciate your comment and it was nice seeing this answer which I'd completely forgotten about.   As if by chance, I'd recently watched a video on youtube about how the 2.1 inverse square or 1.9 inverse square breaks the elipse, so I think I was wrong to say an inverse cube would be still be an ellipse.  , It would probably spiral inward.  I'm a little sorry this question was closed, but maybe it's better for the Math forum than here.  It's an interesting subject.   Anyway - thanks again. I appreciate correction being very out of practice and a couple decades removed from grad school.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your nice words, and I didn't mean that as a correction at all; I just replied to the parenthetical question in your answer, “quadric (not sure that's the right word).” I'm 54 and not a string theorist, thus rusty on modern algebra, but I _think_ that "quadric" _sensu stricto_ is a kind of 4D conical section; the sequence of terms _quadratic_, _cubic_… rather calls for _quartic_, _quintic_, etc. But it's pure mathematicians who invent very precise terms which all sound nearly the same to me. We the physicists will understand, as long as it has a "quad" in it. :))

Comment: And I think the closed OT question is ill-posed. "If space were 4D," "if charges repelled only on Mondays,” “if electrons were made of blue cheese...” All these ifs come out of simplistic curiosity, and aren't of the kind that may likely start a productive train of physicist's thought. The Nature is the only way it is, and is already mindbogglingly complex—so complex, in fact, that it even makes physicists who try to untangle this complexity! No one can have an idea how gravity would work in a $E^4$ space. The way it works is defined by the specific geometry of the only spacetime we observe.

Comment: @kkm  True.   Maybe in pure mathematics is might work.  Not here.